# language modeling - model loss and accuracy not improving, model is underfitting

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, language-model

I am trying to build a word-level language model in TensorFlow. My inputs are batches with word id's of shape `(batch_size, seq_length)`, my targets are the inputs shifted one time step to the left (so for each word, the target is the next word in the sequence).

The model receives word embeddings as an input (word embeddings were pre-trained using gensim word2vec). I manually checked that the word embeddings are read in correctly and that they correspond to the right word id's.

Although I have tried out a lot of things, my model is not improving. Even when training for 100 epochs over the full training set, the accuracy remains the same.

What I have tried (without any success):

- Removing dropout. My first goal is to get rid of underfitting
- Different vocabulary size (100, 1000, 10000)
- Using gradient clipping/ not using gradient clipping
- Changing the initialization of the weights
- Data shuffling
- different optimizer (RSMProp, Adam and Gradient Descent)
- larger/smaller model (2-4 hidden layers with 128-256 hidden units)
- different batch size (10, 20, 128)
- different learning rate (0.01, 0.001, 0.1)
- different loss function (sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits or tf.contrib.seq2seq.sequence_loss)
- refeeding/not refeeding the final state of the LSTM during training*

In the beginning, both loss and accuracy are improving. Also, the model is adapting its predictions. But then, after some epochs over the full training set, loss and accuracy stay constant. Also, the model predictions aren't changing anymore and it gets stuck.
Here is an example that shows the development of loss and accuracy for the same input sequence. After epoch 30, nothing is changing anymore:

```
2017-11-08 06:59:24,298 - DEBUG - Targets: [  91    4    9  116  237 1953  240    3    2    1    0    2    1    9  144 351   29  299   24  453]
 2017-11-08 06:59:24,299 - DEBUG - Predicted sequence: [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 2017-11-08 06:59:24,299 - INFO - Current epoch: 1
 2017-11-08 06:59:24,299 - INFO - Current training step: 2000
 2017-11-08 06:59:24,299 - INFO - Current loss: 107.67147064208984
 2017-11-08 06:59:24,299 - INFO - Current accuracy: 0.1599999964237213


 2017-11-08 07:04:09,559 - DEBUG - Targets: [  91    4    9  116  237 1953  240    3    2    1    0    2    1    9  144 351   29  299   24  453]
 2017-11-08 07:04:09,560 - DEBUG - Predicted sequence: [ 4  4  6  6 16  0  0  3  2  1  9  2  1  0  0  4  0  0  4  8]
 2017-11-08 07:04:09,560 - INFO - Current epoch: 5
 2017-11-08 07:04:09,560 - INFO - Current training step: 2000
 2017-11-08 07:04:09,560 - INFO - Current loss: 97.8116455078125
 2017-11-08 07:04:09,560 - INFO - Current accuracy: 0.2150000035762787


2017-11-08 07:43:03,875 - DEBUG - Targets: [  91    4    9  116  237 1953  240    3    2    1    0    2    1    9  144 351   29  299   24  453]
 2017-11-08 07:43:03,875 - DEBUG - Predicted sequence: [ 6  4  9 55 47  0  5  3  2  1  9  2  1  0 55 24  0  0  3  6]
 2017-11-08 07:43:03,876 - INFO - Current epoch: 30
 2017-11-08 07:43:03,876 - INFO - Current training step: 2000
 2017-11-08 07:43:03,876 - INFO - Current loss: 84.75357055664062
 2017-11-08 07:43:03,876 - INFO - Current accuracy: 0.2549999952316284
```

I have been working on this for a week already and I don't know what I can try out anymore. I would be super grateful for any tips or ideas.

The important parts of the code are here:

```
    def build_graph(self, graph):
    with graph.as_default():
        tf.set_random_seed(self.random_seed)

        with tf.variable_scope('embedding'):
            embedding_matrix = tf.get_variable(name='embedding_matrix', shape=self.embds.shape, initializer=tf.constant_initializer(self.embds), trainable=False)

        with tf.name_scope('input'):
            self.input_batch = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, shape=(None, self.seq_length))
            self.inputs = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embedding_matrix, self.input_batch)
            self.label_batch = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, shape=(None, self.seq_length))

        with tf.name_scope('rnn'):
            # Set up the RNN architecture
            cells = []

            for i in range(self.n_layers):
                cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(self.n_hidden, initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())#use_peepholes=True,

                # Add dropout (only used during training)
                # cell = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(
                #     cell,
                #     output_keep_prob=(1.0 if not self.config['train'] else
                #                       self.dropout_keep_prob))
                cells.append(cell)


            cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(
                cells, state_is_tuple=True)

            # Create a zero-filled state tensor as an initial state
            self.init_state = cell.zero_state(self.batch_size, tf.float32)

            # Create a recurrent neural network
            output, self.final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(
                cell,
                inputs=self.inputs,
                initial_state=self.init_state)

            # OLD VERSION
            # self.logits = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(outputs, self.vocab_size, activation_fn=None)

            # NEW VERSION
            # Try out part of tensorflow tutorial

            self.output_flat = tf.reshape(output, [-1, cell.output_size])
            softmax_w = tf.get_variable("softmax_w", [self.n_hidden, self.vocab_size], dtype=tf.float32)

            softmax_b = tf.get_variable("softmax_b", [self.vocab_size], dtype=tf.float32)
            logits = tf.nn.xw_plus_b(self.output_flat, softmax_w, softmax_b)
            # Reshape logits to be a 3-D tensor for sequence loss
            self.logits = tf.reshape(logits, [self.batch_size, self.seq_length, self.vocab_size])

            # Use the contrib sequence loss and average over the batches
            loss = tf.contrib.seq2seq.sequence_loss(
                self.logits,
                self.label_batch,
                tf.ones([self.batch_size, self.seq_length], dtype=tf.float32),
                average_across_timesteps=False, average_across_batch=True)

            self.loss = tf.reduce_sum(loss)


        with tf.name_scope('prediction'):

            # Compute real-valued predictions of the network
            self.predictions = tf.argmax(self.logits, axis=2)

            # Compute the softmax                
            # softmax_ce = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=self.label_batch, logits=self.logits)

        #with tf.name_scope("loss"):
            # Compute the loss (cross-entropy)
            # self.loss = tf.reduce_mean(softmax_ce)

        with tf.name_scope("metrics"):
            # Compute accuracy and perplexity for evaluation

            correct_predictions = tf.to_float(tf.equal(self.label_batch, self.predictions))

            self.perplexity = tf.reduce_mean(tf.exp(softmax_ce))
            self.accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(correct_predictions)

        with tf.name_scope('train'):
            # Create a global step variable
            self.global_step = tf.Variable(
                0,
                trainable=False,
                name="global_step",
                collections=[ tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_STEP, tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES ])

            # Get all variables created with trainable=True
            parameters = tf.trainable_variables()
            # Compute the gradient of the loss w.r.t to the params
            gradients = tf.gradients(self.loss, parameters)
            # Clip the gradients. How this works: Given a tensor t, and a maximum
            # clip value clip_norm the op normalizes t so that its L2-norm is less
            # than or equal to clip_norm
            clipped_gradients, _ = tf.clip_by_global_norm(gradients, self.clip_norm)

            self.optimizer =  tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=self.lr, epsilon=0.1)
            # Apply the optimizer              
            self.train_step = self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(clipped_gradients, parameters), global_step=self.global_step)

            # If not clipping the gradients, minimize the loss directly
            # self.train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(self.lr).minimize(self.loss, global_step=self.global_step)
            # self.train_step = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(self.lr).minimize(self.loss, global_step=self.global_step)

        self._create_summaries()

    return graph


def train(self, save_every=20):
    with self.graph.as_default():

        # Initialize the state of the network
        feed2 = np.zeros((self.batch_size, self.n_hidden))
        t = tuple((feed2, feed2))
        _current_state = np.array([t, t])
        training_step = 0

        for epoch_id in range(0, self.n_epochs):     
            m, n = self.x_train.shape
            self.n_batches = int(m//self.batch_size)

            for batch_number in range(0, self.n_batches):
                training_step += 1
                from_index = batch_number*self.batch_size
                to_index = (batch_number+1)*self.batch_size
                _inputs = self.x_train[from_index:to_index,:]
                _labels = self.y_train[from_index:to_index,:]

                # Run training step
                # The final state of the net is fed back into the net 
                _logits, _predictions, _train_step, _current_state, _loss, _acc, summary = self.sess.run(
                        [self.logits,
                        self.predictions,
                        self.train_step,
                        self.final_state,
                        self.loss,
                        self.accuracy,
                        #self.perplexity,
                        self.merged],
                        feed_dict={
                            self.input_batch: _inputs,
                            self.label_batch: _labels,
                            self.init_state[0][0]: _current_state[0][0],
                            self.init_state[0][1]: _current_state[0][1],
                            self.init_state[1][0]: _current_state[1][0],
                            self.init_state[1][1]: _current_state[1][1],
                           })

                pred = _predictions[0]

                if batch_number % 2000 == 0:
                    self.sw.add_summary(summary, training_step)
                    tf.logging.debug("Targets: {}".format(_labels[0]))
                    tf.logging.debug("Predicted sequence: {}".format(pred))
                    tf.logging.info("Current epoch: {}".format(epoch_id))
                    tf.logging.info("Current training step: {}".format(batch_number))
                    tf.logging.info("Current loss: {}".format(_loss))
                    tf.logging.info("Current accuracy: {}".format(_acc))
                    tf.logging.info("Current perplexity: {}".format(_perpl))

            self.save(epoch_id)
```

Comment: Is your loss getting smaller as you train?

Comment: Only in the beginning. I've added details in the post!

Comment: So, it seems that your network does, in fact, learn, just doesn't learn as much as you want. And you are saying that it continues learning for about 30 epochs before it stops making progress. So my next question is, when you measure accuracy, are you measuring against the training set or against a separate validation set?

Comment: Against the training set!

Comment: The situation doesn't change when having fewer classes, i.e. when having a smaller vocabulary. So even when the problem is not complex, the network stops learning/adapting its predictions after some amount of epochs

Comment: Does it always stop around the same epoch or does that change based on the vocabulary size?

Comment: I have just tested it. When using a smaller vocabulary size, the network stops improving already around epoch 15

Comment: So, the reason I asked the last question is that if the network was always stopping around the same epoch, it would suggest that maybe the network got to capcity and you needed a bigger network. But since it seems to stop learning earlier with a simpler vocabulary, it seems to suggest that maybe it learns as much as it can and struggles to generalize better. So maybe your training dataset is not consistent enough?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158544/discussion-between-lemon-and-mad-wombat).